# How to define normal function with one type

Tags: typescript

Maybe I'am missing something, but can i define function with one (existing type)?

[Sandbox.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFADwFxTgVwLYBGEATgJRIB8UBA9jQDYQCGCUA9G1AMYtw3DVoXABYsA5hAAmAKGlcacAM4CmxYjQDu8LPCSo05RFQDe0qFGIRgOYggCEaaQF9ZHKMM0B%20aQDMccLmAASwVzPmI8JnptWAR0clMLKxt7RycgA)

```
type Fn = (x: number) => boolean  // cannot be changed

const arrowFn: Fn = (x) => {
  return !x
}

// how?
function  normalFn: Fn (x) {
 return !x
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Function keyword with const too:

```
const normalFn: Fn = function (x) {
  return !x;
};
```

But you need a left hand-side to assign a type to, such as a variable, constant, class (and annotate) method etc.